# Get parameters from a flask api

Tags: python, angularjs, flask, cors, flask-restful

I am trying to make my angular application communicate with an API built in Flask. All goes well until I try to make a get request to Flask and I try to retrieve its parameters in Flask.
N.B.: If parameters are not involved it's fine and sending the parameters the other way around also works fine.

So here is my flask code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app,resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})

class Load(Resource):
    def get(self) :
        return json.dumps(['test1','test2','test3'])

class Save(Resource):
    def get(self) :
        print json.loads(request.args.get('data'));
        return make_response('', 201)

api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(Load, '/api/load')
api.add_resource(Save, '/api/save')
```

And here is my client side code

```
$scope.load = function()
{                 
      $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/load").then(function(result)
      {
                info = JSON.parse(result.data);
                $scope.elems.push(...info); // Some array is filled
      });
}

$scope.save = function()
{
      $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/save",{data: JSON.stringify($scope.elems)})
                    .then(function(result){});
}
```

The "load" works great while the "save" gives me the error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

In case it may help I tried to remove the "request.args.get" line and I get no error. Any clue?

Answer (score -1):

I solved the issue. I am not sure why/how though so if anybody has a more complete answer feel free to add/modify. So the issue is that CORS(app) allows communication one way but not the other. To fix it you have to add the correct headers when you do the request from angularjs.

For this purpose I think it's not possible to use $http.get because you cannot specify headers. The possibilities are:

- Use $.get() from jQuery that apparently has the needed headers already (this is what worked for me)
- Use $http and put explicit headers

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl',
  headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
})
```